# Test Data For Visa or Mastercard

Tags: c#, testing, test-data

I need a virtual or test data for visa or master card to test my system like Authorization code, card number and expiry date?

Answer (score 6):

Is this any help:

http://www.infomerchant.net/creditcardprocessing/credit_card_test_numbers.html
http://www.rimmkaufman.com/rkgblog/2007/11/09/credit-card-test-numbers/

```
American Express           378282246310005  
American Express           371449635398431  
American Express Corporate 378734493671000  
Australian BankCard        5610591081018250  
Diners Club                30569309025904  
Diners Club                38520000023237  
Discover                   6011111111111117  
Discover                   6011000990139424  
JCB                        3530111333300000  
JCB                        3566002020360505  
MasterCard                 5555555555554444  
MasterCard                 5105105105105100  
Visa                       4111111111111111  
Visa                       4012888888881881  
Visa                       4222222222222  
Dankort (PBS)              76009244561  
Dankort (PBS)              5019717010103742  
Switch/Solo (Paymentech)   6331101999990016
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://www.fakenamegenerator.com in the past for creating realistic name, address and credit card data (with expiry dates and CCV). You can order bulk sets in various formats as well.